# Wicket Session with more than one user logged in

Tags: java, apache, session, wicket

I am building my first Java Application with Wicket and have a bit of a problem with Wicket Sessions.

My Problem: When a second User logs into the application he overrides the session for the first user -> both are working on the second session now. Although both Users create a new Session when logging in.

My Code:

WicketSession.java:

```
public class WicketSession extends WebSession {

private UserBean            currentUser;

public WicketSession(Request request) {
    super(request);
}

public static WicketSession get() {
    return (WicketSession) Session.get();
}
// getter/setter
```

in my Application class:

```
@Override
public Session newSession(Request request, Response response) {
    return new WicketSession(request);
}
```

and the login (short version w/o ifs, to make it readable):

```
@Override
public final void onSubmit() {

if (signIn(wiaUsername, wiaPassword)) {
    getSession().bind();
    setResponsePage(new CharListDetail());
} else {
    error("Unknown username/ password");
}
}

private boolean signIn(String username, String password) {
    currentUser = UserProxy.getInstance().getElementByUser(username, password);
    WicketSession.get().setCurrentUser(currentUser);
    return true;    
}
```

This all works fine for one user. But the moment a second user logs in

```
WicketSession.get().setCurrentUser(currentUser);
```

sets the current User to the new User and both logged in Users are the same. How do I prevent this problem?

Comment: Why do you think that the second user override a session? Do you want concurrently sign in two users in the same browser? Two users in different browsers works fine. Even the session is a singleton it is just local thread variable, so you needn't be afraid about it.

Comment: For testing I use two different browsers where I log in with two different users.
I log in with both and display a user specific list. When I switch to the first user and reload the page the list from the second user is shown.

The list is generated like this:
CharProxy.getInstance().getAllCharsForCurrentUser(WicketSession.get().getCurrentUser());

Comment: Check your code for `static` modifiers. Those are typically prone to cross-session pollution. Also make sure you use the latest stable version of Wicket, since older versions have issues with thread-local storage clean up, sometimes leaking results from one user into the request scope of another.

Comment: I just checked again for static modifiers, but couldn't find any problem. It seems to me that wicket is losing the first session when a second one is created even though I use getSession().bind().

Has anyone else any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: I just found out that the sessions are kept for each user, only the currentUser is changed to the new User. (which means that both currentUsers are the same).

How would I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching the net I found the solution.

The problem was that I saved the currentUser as a UserBean and not as a String. I dont know exactly why it doesn't work in Wicket to store the User as a Bean, but now finally it's working.

Comment: Try making your user bean implement Serializable